# Form element affecting position of parent column on IE11 only (until clicked when positioning resets)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have a very bizarre problem that no amount of troubleshooting seems to fix.

I've developed a simple communication opt-in centre with two column layout. On all browsers the columns display as they should however on IE11 the columns positions are swapped until the user clicks anywhere on the form at which point the columns take their correct positions.

I've tried all amount of debugging, and can't seem to fix the problem.

A stripped back version is available at https://codepen.io/hellomw/pen/OjbgRX - I've removed all branding and just included the basic elements that seem to be throwing the errors.

A gif showing the error can be seen at: http://recordit.co/jmSgz2WyIQ

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I'm all out of ideas as to what could be causing this.

Any help much appreciated!

Problematic Section:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col sm-3 left">
            <h1>Update your details</h1>
            <p><strong>Please let us know how we can keep in touch with you..</strong></p>
            <p>To change your subscription preferences please update the details below. Tick the boxes that you’d like to stay subscribed to:</p>
            <form id="preference-options" class="preferences">
                <h3>Emails</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input class="checkbox" name="preference-options[]" id="preference-options-0" value="option-0" type="checkbox"><label for="preference-options-0">Option 0 label</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input class="checkbox" name="preference-options[]" id="preference-options-1" value="option-1" type="checkbox"><label for="preference-options-1">Option 1 label</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input class="checkbox" name="preference-options[]" id="preference-options-2" value="option-2" type="checkbox"><label for="preference-options-2">Option 2 label</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <h3>SMS</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input class="checkbox" name="preference-options[]" id="preference-options-3" value="option-3" type="checkbox"><label for="preference-options-4">Option 3 label</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h3>Postal</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input class="checkbox" name="preference-options[]" id="preference-options-4" value="option-4" type="checkbox"><label for="preference-options-4">Option 4 label</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>

                            <input class="checkbox" name="preference-options[]" id="preference-options-5" value="option-5" type="checkbox"><label for="preference-options-5">Option 5 label</span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button name="action" type="submit" value="update" class="button">Save Preferences</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col sm-2">
            <h2>Other ways to keep in touch</h2>
            <ul class="social">
                <li><img src="assets/img/icon-facebook.png"><a href="#">Like us on Facebook</a></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/icon-twitter.png"><a href="#">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/icon-instagram.png"><a href="#">Follow us on Instagram</a></li>
                <li><img src="assets/img/icon-vimeo.png"><a href="#">Subscribe to our Vimeo</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a stray closing /span tag in your label for `#preference-options-5`, fix that. Rest of validation issues are minor (missing image alt, that should not cause any problems like this.) Do you really have an empty line before the doctype, or is that just in your codepen? Older IE were picky about that and went into quirks mode, I think, but AFAIK that should not be an issue with IE 11 any more either.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. The space before doctype was just on CodePen - I've cleaned up the CodePen and here's a BitBalloon link for a working site: http://economist-reward-44146.bitballoon.com/

Comment: Ok, with that I can reproduce the problem in IE 11. Looks like clicking any actual text elements/labels doesn’t trigger the column swap, but only clicking somewhere on the white background does ... Have you checked if the same thing happens without any JS in the page?

Comment: The only javascript I'm using is modernizr to give support for flexbox and HTML5 elements. Here's the same site without Modernizr and with the <footer> changed to a <div> and display:flex removed from the body (I was using this to push the footer to the bottom): http://hotelier-interface-27153.bitballoon.com/

Comment: What’s weird is that the columns themselves are not even flexboxed, but use simple floating ... You have a `:last-of-type.col { float:right; }` rule in your stylesheet, can you try and remove that and see if it changes things?

Comment: That's right - the grid system is one I've put together myself over the last couple of years but it's not been updated to be fully flexbox as yet. I only tend to use flexbox at the moment for a handful of elements. Float:right removed on the last col here: http://printer-kangaroo-62274.bitballoon.com/

EDIT: That does seem to have fixed things however I've never had a problem with that float:right with this grid system before (and have used this on many live sites!) so I'm baffled as to why it doesn't work here.